# Storing statistical data, do I need DECIMAL, FLOAT or DOUBLE?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, double, decimal

I am creating for fun, but I still want to approach it seriously, a site which hosts various tests. With these tests I hope to collect statistical data.

Some of the data will include the percentage of the completeness of the tests as they are timed. I can easily compute the percentage of the tests but I would like true data to be returned as I store the various different values concerning the tests on completion.

Most of the values are, in PHP floats, so my question is, if I want true statistical data should I store them in MYSQL as FLOAT, DOUBLE or DECIMAL.

I would like to utilize MYSQL'S functions such as `AVG()` and `LOG10()` as well as `TRUNCATE()`. For MYSQL to return true data based off of my values that I insert, what should I use as the database column choice.

I ask because some numbers may or may not be floats such as, 10, 10.89, 99.09, or simply 0.
But I would like true and valid statistical data to be returned.

Can I rely on floating point math for this?

**EDIT**

I know this is a generic question, and I apologise extensively, but for non mathematicians like myself, also I am not a MYSQL expert, I would like an opinion of an expert in this field.

I have done my research but I still feel I have a clouded judgement on the matter. Again I apologise if my question is off topic or not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This **[link](http://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/)** does a good job of explaining what you are looking for.  Here is what is says:

All these three Types, can be specified by the following Parameters (size, d). Where size is the total size of the String, and d represents precision. E.g To store a Number like 1234.567, you will set the Datatype to DOUBLE(7, 3) where 7 is the total number of digits and 3 is the number of digits to follow the decimal point.

FLOAT and DOUBLE, both represent floating point numbers. A FLOAT is for single-precision, while a DOUBLE is for double-precision numbers. A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column. FLOAT is accurate to approximately 7 decimal places, and DOUBLE upto 14.

Decimal’s declaration and functioning is similar to Double. But there is one big difference between floating point values and decimal (numeric) values. We use DECIMAL data type to store exact numeric values, where we do not want precision but exact and accurate values. A Decimal type can store a Maximum of 65 Digits, with 30 digits after decimal point.

**So, for the most accurate and precise value, Decimal would be the best option.**

Comment: That link has a lot of incorrect information. I would not follow its advice.

Comment: Also, if used for indexing or as a key, a float is undesirable because the stored value might differ from the one inserted

Comment: @Linger so if I use somthing like, sum, multiplication functions in select then double is better?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for the benefit of future readers, **this answer is completely wrong and should NOT have been accepted.** `float`, `double`, and `decimal` are all *inexact floating-point* types. As explained in [this much better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/2447250), the primary difference between them is the *numeric base* (2 vs. 10) of the underlying data representation.

Comment: @DavidZhang Are you saying 'Decimal' is a base 10 data representation? In that case, it would be more precise in some cases. For example, storing 0.1 in a base 2 vs base 10.

Comment: @DavidZhang The answer you linked to is for .NET decimal, float, etc. This question is asking about MYSQL

Comment: @SvetAngelov Yes, MySQL `DECIMAL` differs from .NET `decimal` in that it's fixed-point rather than floating-point. I misspoke in my previous comment when I said they were all floating-point. But that doesn't change the fact that all three datatypes are **inherently inexact**, and selecting between them means choosing the *kind of inexactness* you're willing to tolerate.

Comment: Do not use `(m,n)` with `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  It only adds inaccuracies and causes trouble.  It has been removed in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: `DOUBLE` gives about 16 significant digits.  (Yes, that is more than twice the `FLOAT's` precision.)

Answer (score 17):

Unless you are storing decimal data (i.e. currency), you should use a standard floating point type (FLOAT or DOUBLE). DECIMAL is a fixed point type, so can overflow when computing things like SUM, and will be ridiculously inaccurate for LOG10.

There is nothing "less precise" about binary floating point types, in fact, they will be much more accurate (and faster) for your needs. Go with DOUBLE.

Comment: In the docs it is mentioned, "for Decimal " data type the calculations are exact.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-numbers.html

Comment: While summation of fixed point values is exact, other operations (such as division or log10) can't be: there is simply no way to represent the result in fixed point.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource where I can ready more about it, wherever I've read about it, all that is written is that, for exact calculations use Decimal types.

Comment: Any decent coverage of numerical analysis (my favourite is Nick Higham's "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms") will cover fixed and floating point representations.

Comment: Will take a look into it !

Answer (score 14):

**Decimal** : Fixed-Point Types (*Exact* Value). Use it when you care about exact precision like money.

Example: `salary DECIMAL(8,2)`, 8 is the total number of digits, 2 is the number of decimal places. `salary` will be in the range of `-999999.99` to `999999.99`

---

**Float, Double** : Floating-Point Types (*Approximate* Value). Float uses 4 bytes to represent value, Double uses 8 bytes to represent value.

Example: `percentage FLOAT(5,2)`, same as the type decimal, 5 is total digits and 2 is the decimal places. `percentage` will store values between `-999.99` to `999.99`.

Note that they are **approximate** value, in this case:

- Value like `1 / 3.0 = 0.3333333...` will be stored as `0.33` (2 decimal place)
- Value like `33.009` will be stored as `33.01` (rounding to 2 decimal place)

Answer (score 7):

Put it simply, Float and double are not as precise as decimal. decimal is recommended for money related number input.(currency and salary).
Another point need to point out is: Do NOT compare float number using "=","<>", because float numbers are not precise.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `FLOAT`.  And do *not* tack on '(m,n)'.  Do display numbers to a suitable precision with formatting options.  Do *not* expect to get correct answers with "="; for example, `float_col = 0.12` will always return `FALSE`.

For display purposes, use formatting to round the results as needed.

Percentages, averages, etc are all rounded (at least in some cases).  That any choice you make will sometimes have issues.

Use `DECIMAL(m,n)` for currency; use `...INT` for whole numbers; use `DOUBLE for scientific stuff that needs more than 7 digits of precision; use` FLOAT` for everything else.

Transcendentals (such as the `LOG10` that you mentioned) will do their work in `DOUBLE`; they will essentially never be exact.  It is OK to feed it a `FLOAT` arg and store the result in `FLOAT`.

This Answer applies not just to MySQL, but to essentially any database or programming language.  (The details may vary.)

PS:  `(m,n)` has been removed from `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`.  It only added extra rounding and other things that were essentially no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Linger: The website you mention and quote has IMO some imprecise info that made me confused. In the docs I read that when you declare a float or a double, the decimal point is in fact NOT included in the number. So it is not the number of chars in a string but all digits used.

Compare the docs:
"DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D).. Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed"
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/floating-point-types.html

Also the nomenclature in misleading - acc to docs: M is 'precision' and D is 'scale', whereas the website takes 'scale' for 'precision'.

Thought it would be useful in case sb like me was trying to get a picture. 
Correct me if I'm wrong, hope I haven't read some outdated docs:)

Answer (score 1):

Float and Double are Floating point data types, which means that the numbers they store can be precise up to a certain number of digits only. 
For example for a table with a column of float type if you store `7.6543219` it will be stored as `7.65432`.
Similarly the `Double` data type approximates values but it has more precision than `Float`.

When creating a table with a column of `Decimal` data type, you specify the total number of digits and number of digits after decimal to store, and if the number you store is within the range you specified it will be stored exactly.

When you want to store exact values, `Decimal` is the way to go, it is what is known as a fixed data type.