# Divide two integers to get a float in MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, user-defined-functions, integer-division

I'm working on a user defined function in MySQL that takes an integer (mediumint) and divides it by 100 (i.e. 10785 / 100 = 107.85).  The supplied integer is a parameter called time.  I've tried

```
DECLARE dtime FLOAT;
SET dtime = time / 100;
DECLARE ftime VARCHAR(10);
```

which is causing an error, I assume because I'm dividing two integers and assigning it to a float

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'DECLARE ftime VARCHAR(10);
```

I've also tried

```
SET dtime = CAST(time as FLOAT) / 100.0;
```

But that throws an error because it appears you can't cast a number to a float. Finally, I tried using decimal

```
DECLARE dtime DECIMAL(10,10);
SET dtime = CAST(time AS decimal(10,10)) / CAST(100 as decimal(10,10);
DECLARE ftime VARCHAR(10);
```

But throws the same error (`near 'Declare ftime...`).  What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why float vs double? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601975/storing-statistical-data-do-i-need-decimal-float-or-double

Comment: No reason other than I don't need double precision.

Comment: Simple guess: try moving all the `declare` statements to the beginning of the function/procedure, and any other instruction (including the `set` statements) after the `declare`s. Read my answer below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please read the documentation for the `DECLARE` statement syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html)

Quoting from the reference manual (the above link):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and **must be at its start, before any other statements**.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.

Comment: Happy to help. If this was useful, vote it up (and/or accept it ;) )

Comment: I've been trying to accept it. Was told I had to wait 5 minutes. I'm now at 30 seconds :).

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT CAST(time AS decimal) / CAST(100 AS decimal)
```

Comment: Same error.  `DECLARE dtime DECIMAL;  SET dtime = cast(time as decimal) / cast(100 as decimal);`  Error `near 'DECLARE ftime VARCHAR(10);`

Comment: See the answer above. I had assumed declare was at the start of the snip it.