# subtraction in SQL giving incorrect value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains Id, Date and a float value as below:

```
ID      startDt                  Days
1328    2015-04-01 00:00:00.000 15
2444    2015-04-03 00:00:00.000 5.7
1658    2015-05-08 00:00:00.000 6
1329    2015-05-12 00:00:00.000 28.5
1849    2015-06-23 00:00:00.000 28.5
1581    2015-06-30 00:00:00.000 25.5
3535    2015-07-03 00:00:00.000 3
3536    2015-08-13 00:00:00.000 13.5
2166    2015-09-22 00:00:00.000 28.5
3542    2015-11-05 00:00:00.000 13.5
3543    2015-12-18 00:00:00.000 6
2445    2015-12-25 00:00:00.000 5.7
4096    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 7.5
2446    2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 5.7
4287    2016-02-11 00:00:00.000 13.5
4288    2016-02-18 00:00:00.000 13.5
4492    2016-03-02 00:00:00.000 19.7
2447    2016-03-25 00:00:00.000 5.7
```

I am using a stored procedure which adds up the Days then subtracts it from a fixed value stored in a variable.

The total in the table is 245 and the variable is set to 245 so I should get a value of 0 when subtracting the two. However, I am getting a value of 5.6843418860808E-14 instead. I cant figure out why this is the case and I have gone and re entered each number in the table but I still get the same result.

This is my sql statement that I am using to calculate the result:

```
Declare @AL_Taken as float
Declare @AL_Remaining as float
Declare @EntitledLeave as float

Set @EntitledLeave=245

set @AL_Taken= (select sum(Days) from tblALMain)

Set @AL_Remaining=@EntitledLeave-@AL_Taken


Select @EntitledLeave, @AL_Taken, @AL_Remaining
```

The select returns the following:
245, 245, 5.6843418860808E-14

Can anyone suggest why I am getting this number when I should be getting 0?

Thanks for the help

Rob

Comment: 5.6843418860808E-14 = 0.000000000000056843418860808.  For most practical purposes, the value is 0.  This is one of the vagaries of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Because float is not an exact data type, and you're getting a rounding error.   Use decimal datatype and the problem should go away.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff states--this is an issue with floating point arithmetic.  Is there any reason you aren't using integers (for whole days, as opposed to fractions of a day), which would avoid this problem?

Comment: @Russ Some might take 1/2 day off

Comment: If you want precision, dont' use float!  If you need to save space and precisions isn't necessary use float.  great comments on other stack questions relative to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601975/storing-statistical-data-do-i-need-decimal-float-or-double  Simply put: it's working as it should, you just have the wrong expectation.

Comment: Someone is taking 5 days 16 hours 48 minutes off (=5.7 days)? Do you really need to calculate something on that precision? Maybe datetime would be better suited for that.

Comment: Look at using the DATEDIFF() function

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. This seems to be an isolated case since over 100 people use the application and its only this person who seems to have this figure. @Jamez: the column heading is a bit misleading. Some people have leave calculated in hours and the amount of time is entered by the user. Not sure why they entered 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data type to Decimal as Tab Allenman suggested and this resolved my issue. I still dont understand why I didnt get zero when using float as all the values added up to 245 exactly (I even re-entered the values manually) and 245 - 245 should have given me 0.

Thanks again for all the comments and explanations.

Rob

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for this article. Explains perfectly