# MySQL Variable for human height (tinyint or smallint)

Tags: mysql, variables, types, tinyint

I am new to SQL! So if I want to add a person's height to my table (ex 1.86) what variable type should I use?? Tinyint or Smallint?

Comment: You should probably mention which SQL engine are you using, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle etc. If you want to store the height value as a decimal then you can't use an integer type such as TINYINT, you will need to look at fixed-point or floating-point data types instead. If you were to use an integer type (to store centimetres for example rather than fractional meters) then an UNSIGNED TINYINT would limit you to a maximum value of 255 and a SIGNED TINYINT to 127, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use

to store :: 1.86 AS human height, use  DOUBLE(3,2)

in above case, you may also use DECIMAL(3,2), but DECIMAL is mostly used for financial figures as DOUBLE causes some rounding issues.

[Storing statistical data, do I need DECIMAL, FLOAT or DOUBLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601975/storing-statistical-data-do-i-need-decimal-float-or-double)

if you can convert 1.86 meters into cm

then to store :: 186 cm as human height, use SMALLINT

for optimal datatypes :

http://www.developwebsites.net/choose-optimal-mysql-data-type/

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the decimal point and store it as centimeters.

Then, just use an `UNSIGNED TINYINT` ([max value of 255](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)  = 2.55 meters) or a `SMALLINT` ([max value of 32767](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)).

It'd use a fraction of the byte storage (compared to a `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL`) and is arguably nicer to work with.